# Colour in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view

Does somebody has an idea why the colour of the material looks so weird in the viewport? I checked the world settings and the lighting, and did nothing with nodes, just wanted to assign the colour to the mech. Maybe I changed something by accident? I know it must be a stupid question for you guys, but I’m still a newbie. Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What particular part looks "weird" to you? You have two materials assigned one is called "Gelb" the other "Schokobraun". Because of the curvature some faces have a darker shade.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I just wondered why it isn’t shown in the viewport as represented in the materials preview. I cranked up the lighting and it became better, and I should’ve checked it with the viewport shading view.